# Android Studio download gradle takes forever

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Everytime an imported project requires a specific version of gradle I don't have, it starts to sync. At this time, I close Android Studio, connect to vpn, and reopen Android Studio to sync gradle; however, sync never ends. Then I go to .gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-xxx-all and nothing is downloaded (zip.part 0Kb). When I connect to vpn I can access gradle.org and download manually. Is this a bug with Android Studio or gradle?

There are many similar questions and most are solved by manually downloading the zip package. None solve the problem completely, though.

Answer (score 1):

Follow below step to set automatically gradle sync in your android studio.

**File** -> **Settings** -> **Build,Execution,Deployment** ->**Build tools** -> **gradle** ->
check **Use Default gradle wrapper(recommended)** radiobutton.

Also follow below step to restart your android studio for invalid cache restart.

**File** > **Invalidate Caches/Restart** (you can also manually remove the cache at ~/Library/Caches/{yourIDEName} and restart the IDE)

Then save settings and rebuild your project.

**Edit:** See [Android 1.5 Gradle Sync never completes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33833095/android-1-5-gradle-sync-never-completes) to get more idea.

I hope its helps you.

Comment: Thank you, learned how to manually remove cache. I think you method will solve problem when the problem reappear. The real problem is : next time another gradle version is required, it will broke too. anything i can do to prevent that?